# Resources For Java EE 6

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

I want to learn Java EE 6. I am new to the entire EE thing but I am proficient with Core java. Can someone suggest a good book to learn this? I checked out Amazon and Oracle's website but I have got mixed reviews on them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [J2EE Book Recommendation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129059/j2ee-book-recommendation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try one of [Antonio Goncalvez](http://www.antoniogoncalves.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/WebHome) books, they're good for beginners in JavaEE realms.